# How to redirect a specific url to a different domain (Nginx)

Tags: url, nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to redirect https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/

To

https://anotherDomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/

I tried

```
rewrite ^(/wp-json/wp/v2/.*) $scheme://anotherDomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ break;
```

And it redirects to https://anotherDomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/
and then keeps redirecting, redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

Try `$scheme://anotherDomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/$request_uri` where `$request_uri` is the full URI including arguments.

As a option you can redirects (301) to new domain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

Take at look [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: i tried 
location /wp-json/wp/v2/ {
return 301 $scheme://NewDomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2;
}

Only worked after i removed the slash after v2, which is weird

Comment: @Icarus request path must be exactly equal to `/wp-json/wp/v2/` including last slash. Probably `NewDomain.com/wp/v2/` (with slash) is not mapped in NGINX. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: What if i want to redirect everying at https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/
like https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/generalinfo
to https://AnotherDomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/generalinfo